# C# namespace in a class

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, methods, nested

I have basic knowledge of classes and methods. I can make classes, and define methods for them:

```
myClass.awesome("test"); (example)
```

But I saw a class have the following method:

```
anotherClass.something.methodName(arguments);
```

How do I create a method that has additional namespace(s). I tried:

```
public Class test
{
    namespace subname
    {
        public void Test()
        {
            return;
        }
    }

    //also i tried:
    public void lol.Test()
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

But they both say that its not to be done like that, how do it correctly, so I can order/group my methods better?

Please don't ask why, or give a alternative, I just want to make a class that has this kind of methods(`Class.sub.Method()` or `Class.sub.sub....sub.Method()`)

Thank you for reading my question, and possibly giving ans answer :)

Comment: do what correctley? You can't declare namespaces inside classes.

Comment: Ok, Here is your answer: Take a look at [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22769/Introduction-to-Object-Oriented-Programming-Concep) its about [Object Oriented Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> i saw a class have the following method:
>   anotherClass.something.methodName(arguments);

The method is not from the class `anotherClass` instead it is from the class of object `something`.

The class `anotherClass` has a field/property `something` which is of another class type, that class has the method `methodName`

Answer (score 0):

What you think you have seen is not correct actually. It can be any of the followings:

- `anotherClass` is namespace, `something` is class, `methodName` is static method
- `anotherClass` is an object, `something` is a property of `anotherClass`, `methodName` is a method

Answer (score 0):

If you want to group your methods you should consider using static classes like this:

```
public class Test
{
    public static class InnerGroup
    {
        public static void Method1() { }
    }
    public static class AnotherInnerGroup
    {
        public static void Method2() { }
    }
}
```

or class properties like this:

```
public class Test
{
    public class InnerGroup
    {
        public static void Method1() { }
    }

    public class AnotherInnerGroup
    {
        public static void Method2() { }
    }

    public InnerGroup InnerGroup { get; set; }

    public AnotherInnerGroup AnotherInnerGroup { get; set; }

    public Test()
    {
        InnerGroup = new InnerGroup();
        AnotherInnerGroup= new AnotherInnerGroup();
    }
}
```

Hope you understood.